# Adding images to an HTML document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, image

I've tried some HTML DOM code from several sites, but it isn't working. It isn't adding anything. Does anyone have a working example on this?

```
this.img = document.createElement("img");
this.img.src = "img/eqp/"+this.apparel+"/"+this.facing+"_idle.png";
src = getElementById("gamediv");
src.appendChild(this.img)
```

But it isn't adding anything to the div `gamediv`. I've tried `document.body` as well, with no result.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementById()` in line 3.

If you try this right now in the console:

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
var src = document.getElementById("header");
src.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

... you'd get this:

[image]

Comment: this.img = document.createElement("img");
 this.img.src = "img/eqp/"+this.apparel+"/"+this.facing+"_idle.png";
 src = document.getElementById("gamediv");
 src.appendChild(this.img);

Changed it now, but it still doesn't pop up in the div gamediv.

Comment: @klausbyskov: Thanks for fixing the typo.

Comment: @Anonymous: Could it be that the `src` path is incorrect? Can you try an image with an absolute path, that you know for sure exists? Such as: `http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png`

Comment: Running the code it says src is null. But I am sure I made a div with gamediv as an id.
<div id="gamediv"></div>

Comment: I know the src is correct, the comment above is what firebug tells me when I select break on error

Comment: @Anonymous: You may want to update the question with this info. It may help you get more answers.

Comment: This helpful simple and straightforward

Comment: in case you are wondering (as I was) you can add an extra line to change the image size following var img = document.createElement("img"); add this: img.style.width = "100px"; and: img.style.height = "100px";- adjust the sizes accordingly

Answer (score 6):

With a little research i found that javascript does not know that a Document Object Exist unless the Object has Already loaded before the script code (As JavaScript reads down a page).

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insert(){
            var src = document.getElementById("gamediv");
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "img/eqp/"+this.apparel+"/"+this.facing+"_idle.png";
            src.appendChild(img);
        }
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="gamediv">
         <script type="text/javascript">
             insert();
         </script>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'img/eqp/' + this.apparel + '/' + this.facing + '_idle.png';
document.getElementById('gamediv').appendChild(img)
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('<img/>')
.attr('src','img/eqp/' + this.apparel + '/' + this.facing + '_idle.png')
.appendTo('#gamediv');
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use Image() instead

Instead of using `document.createElement()` use `new Image()`

```js
const myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

> The Image() constructor creates a new HTMLImageElement instance. It is functionally equivalent to document.createElement('img').

Answer (score 2):

or you can just

```
<script> 
document.write('<img src="/*picture_location_(you can just copy the picture and paste   it into the script)*\"')
document.getElementById('pic')
</script>
<div id="pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the **this** statements too

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "img/eqp/"+this.apparel+"/"+this.facing+"_idle.png";
src = document.getElementById("gamediv");
src.appendChild(this.img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to ponder:

1. [Use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question) [jquery](http://www.jquery.com)
2. Which `this` is your code refering to
3. Isnt  `getElementById` usually `document.getElementById`?
4. If the image is not found, [are you sure your browser would tell you](http://www.theadminzone.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24817)?