# How to insert an image with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have image URL's in a js file as objects.

How do I grab those images and insert them into the HTML dynamically?

I have tried using id's and `getElementById` but that didn't work.

Comment: *What* didn't work?  We can't help you with your code unless you share it.

Comment: This shows you how to add them into a container element... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735881/adding-images-to-the-html-with-javascript

Comment: Please post your current relevant code you have tried to grab those images as we can't help you or see what is wrong with it without the code. See [**How to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed HTML (switched classes and IDs to make IDs unique) and added an image ID for simplicity:

`<div id="msgStyle1" class="message">Waiting for image</div>
<div id="imgStyle1" class="message">
    <img src="" id="image" />
</div>`

JS:

`document.getElementById('image').src = 'http://yourImagePathHere';`

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/N3rCm/

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you.