# How should I add multiple images from a folder(present locally on my PC) in a 9x9 grid in HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
.card {
  width: 20rem;
  margin: 30px;
}

.image-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  height: 310px;
  overflow: auto;
  /* For 3 columns */
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="imgcontainer">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="card">

      <div class="image-grid-container">


        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">



      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          LR
        </h4>

        <p class="card-text">
          Low Resolution Images before applying Algorithm.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     LR FOLDER 
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="image-grid-container">

      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          Loading Results...
        </h4>

        <p class="card-text">
          Developer Guy love to develop front-end and back-end
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     ESRGAN
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="image-grid-container">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200120152724/gfg_icon.png">
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          HR
        </h4>

        <p class="card-text">
          High Resolution Images after applying Algorithm.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     HR FOLDER 
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I have made a 9x9 grid using HTML and CSS.

It contains 9 images which can be scrolled down/up using scroller.

Now I have around 100,000 images which I have to display in the grid.

Is there anything I can do... I am new to frontend.

This is the look of the grid:

[image: this is how the grid looks like also the scroller.]

I have to display images from the folder using some loops.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically decide which images to load, or do you know exactly the 9 images? Do you have some of your existing code you can add?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please to do not post images without your code example. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yeah i have added the code.

Comment: Actually I have to add multiple images from a folder.

Comment: If you want to do anything programmatic you are going to have to use some Javascript. If you don't want to use an existing framework/library you can do what you are trying to do by manipulating the DOM via JS, like this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735894/1168004

Comment: I need to display multiple images