# Why isnt my js object outputting the images that I put in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've tried this code and I'm pretty sure the function works just fine, it's just not outputting the images that I put in the object, so can someone help me make it do so?
So far this is what I've done

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<script>
    function test() {
        const test1 = window.prompt("Yayınevi gir");
        const correctNameBooks = books.filter(book => book.name === test1);
        console.log(correctNameBooks);
    }
    let books = [
        {
            name: 'Tonguç',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/nv8gp4ms60161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Nitelik',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/nlhp8ij770161.png'
        },
        {
            name: "Sonuç",
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/lhy1liao70161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Supara',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/t7263o2c80161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Palme',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/24gn3zdg80161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Gezegen',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/ibqo7b9j80161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Karekök',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/dkos5tds80161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Arı',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/oer1chfv80161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Okyanus',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/xkbv0gg290161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Hız',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/w167386b90161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Sınav',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/02md3r9d90161.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Esen',
            imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/k4ars8mf90161.png'
        }
    ]
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick=test()>test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

To sum the code up, it **should** output the images where their names match the user's input

Comment: Seems to work fine? What is the issue?

Comment: what do you mean by *not outputting*? It doesn't show anything at all? it shows the wrong info? Please, be more specific. What is the desired result and what is exaclty happening. It seems to be working for me

Comment: This works perfectly fine? I just copied the name and pasted it into the `prompt` and it worked.

Comment: @Dominik im trying to make the keys,images

Comment: Oh so you're wanting to display the images? That can't happen with a `console.log()`

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to code this for you rather than help you find the bug... That's not how SO works

Comment: @Samathingamajig oh,then how can i do it?

Comment: @Dominik i mean not really i just wanna know where im going wrong

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735881/adding-images-to-an-html-document-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the images, you need to use `<img>` tags in HTML. With this example, you can have multiple books by the same name.

More explanations are in the comments.

```js
function test() {
    const test1 = window.prompt("Yayınevi gir");
    const correctNameBooks = books.filter(book => book.name === test1);
    console.log(correctNameBooks);
    
    const imageContainer = document.querySelector("div#image-container"); // Grab the parent/container
    imageContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Remove all the children
    for (let book of correctNameBooks) {
        const newImage = document.createElement("img"); // Create a new image element/tag
        newImage.src = book.imgUrl; // Set its source to the book's image url
        imageContainer.appendChild(newImage); // Add the image to the image container's children
    }
}
let books = [
    {
        name: 'Tonguç',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/nv8gp4ms60161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Nitelik',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/nlhp8ij770161.png'
    },
    {
        name: "Sonuç",
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/lhy1liao70161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Supara',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/t7263o2c80161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Palme',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/24gn3zdg80161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Gezegen',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/ibqo7b9j80161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Karekök',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/dkos5tds80161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Arı',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/oer1chfv80161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Okyanus',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/xkbv0gg290161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Hız',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/w167386b90161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Sınav',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/02md3r9d90161.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Esen',
        imgUrl: 'https://i.redd.it/k4ars8mf90161.png'
    }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick=test()>test</button>
    <div id="image-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u explain the "imageContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Remove all the children",what am i supposed to put in between the quotation marks?

Comment: Absolutely nothing goes between the `""`. That sets the `innerHTML` to be completely empty, therefore removing the children. If you want the images to stay there on each subsequent button press, you can delete that line.