# I cannot seem to get my Img to display on my webpage

Tags: javascript

I double checked the SRC. i'm a newbie so perhaps there is something i'm not seeing.

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener('load', generateFaces);
  let numberOfFaces = 5;
  const theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
  const theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
//   const theBody =  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  function generateFaces() {
      for (let i=0; i<numberOfFaces; i++) {
          let face = document.createElement ('img');
          face.setAttribute("src",'images/smile.png');
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question / answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735881/adding-images-to-an-html-document-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only creating the img objects but you also need to append them to your div. You can use the following code for appending:

```
theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
```

See Stackblitz for working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-jdsz4u?file=index.html